# OSX Yosemite Dock magnification disabled

Tags: macos, dock, osx-yosemite, magnification

I am running latest Yosemite 10.10.4 on latest MacMini model. Somehow the magnification is enabled BUT the checkbox is not editable so I cannot turn it OFF or change the size. I am a Mac user for MANY years and have never seen this. How to change it? I have also run PRAM reset, repaired permissions. Nothing I have found on web is working.

[See this link for screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vjfcuxymchdxviw/Magnification.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

> To temporarily enable Dock magnification on your Mac, hold down Control+Shift as you mouse over the Dock icons. To turn it off again, just release the Control and Shift keys.

Source: http://mactoids.com/keyboard-shortcut-for-dock-magnification/

Also to increase the maximum magnification size, try running this in terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.dock largesize -float 128.000000 

killall Dock
```

Source: http://www.maclife.com/article/features/4_terminal_tricks_customizing_your_os_x_dock

Comment: Shortcut is not working. The terminal command also does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

System preferences / Dock / check magnification checkbox

Else in terminal run

defaults write com.apple.dock largesize -float 128.000000

killall Dock

Comment: I hoped the "I am a Mac user for many years and never see this." will be understood in a way that I know where the Dock features settings are. The problem is that the checkbox is not editable.